# Differentiating 2 sides of an equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm self-learning the course Multivariable Calculus of MIT and i'm stuck at understanding the concept of "Constrained Differentials".

In the course's note, there is something like:
Suppose $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, it is claimed that that we can differentiate both sides of this constraint to get $2x dx + 2y dy = 0$

Could you please explain me why the operation like that valid ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think you'd get $dx=0$, wouldn't you?

Comment: thank you, i have edited the question so that it is true.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a constraint it means that the values of $x$ and $y$ are not independent, but linked by $f(x,y)=0$. You are going to consider increments $dx$ and $dy$ that keep you on the same curve to the first approximation, that is you need $f(x+dx,y+dy)=0$. But $f(x+dx,y+dy)=f(x,y)+df((x,y),(dx,dy))$ up to higher order infinitesimals, so you need $df=f_xdx+f_ydy=0$.

For the second part, you get $dx=0$.